# Storing list variables as a string and storing it as a variable

Tags: python

I am trying to enter list items into a string. I then want to store the string as a variable and print it out in another function. The code I have got so far is:

```
def b(): 

    ID = [0, 1, 2]
    ID2 = 'ID={0}.{1}.{2}'.format(*ID) 
    return ID2 

if __name__ == '__main__': ID2 = b() 


def c(ID2): 
    print ID2 

if __name__ == '__main__': myObject = c(ID2)
```

The output I get is:

```
[0, 1, 2]
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

I was returning the list as well as ID2. This was causing the problem. Sorry about this.

The code is now working. Thanks

Comment: is that an actual code you're using?

Comment: @ SilentGhost I am using similar code to this. Only the list is generated not declared.

Comment: Can you specify the sort of output you are expecting?

Comment: @chrissygormley: quite clearly what is returned from `b` is not a string but a list. If you could test your code in IDLE, you'd see the reason for this error

Comment: If this is really the case, I suggest you consider creating a class and defining the `__repr__()` function for it to print out the ID as above?

Comment: @chrissygormley: I'd suggest you vote to delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def b():
    ID = [0, 1, 2]
    ID2 = ('ID=%d.%d.%d' % tuple(ID))
    return ID2

if __name__ == '__main__': ID2 = b()

def c(ID2):
    print ID2

if __name__ == '__main__': myObject = c(ID2)
```

works for me, don't have python3 handy so cannot try with the .format()-syntax.

However `myObject = c(ID2)` does not make sense, function c() does not return anything

Comment: How about when the length of list is more than 100. Will you write %d hundred times?

Comment: If the list is longer than 3, I think I'll do a `"ID=%s" % ".".join( ["%d" % x for x in list])`

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
>>> ''.join([str(x) for x in [1, 2, 3]])
'123'
```

Comment: I am really not sure what exactly he wants. I am hoping he wants the result some thing like this "ID=0,ID=1,ID=2"

Comment: the point is that OP doesn't have problem with string formatting. His problem is that he was returning from `b` before he even performed the formatting, and not this code wasn't posted.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change [0,1,2] to "0.1.2" (like version string in your previous questions), you could do like this.

```
>>> '.'.join(map(str,[0, 1, 2]))
'0.1.2'
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You should probably not have global variable names that match your function parameter names.  It's legal  but very, very confusing.  And a debugging nightmare.
2. You should probably not use ALL UPPERCASE VARIABLE NAMES.  It's odd-looking and makes your code hard to read for experienced Python programmers.
3. You should probably not have multiple `if __name__ == "__main__"` sections.  It's very, very confusing and a debugging nightmare.

I suspect that these "cosmetic" issues are making it hard to figure out what's really wrong with your program.

```
def b(): 
    id = [0, 1, 2]
    aString = 'ID={0}.{1}.{2}'.format(*id) 
    return aString 

def c(id2): 
    print id2 

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    someString = b() 
    myObject = c(someString)
```

You might find this a little easier to debug.

My output.

```
ID=0.1.2
```

BTW. Your function `c` always returns `None`.  So the `myObject = c(someString)` doesn't make a lot of sense.